# Meaning of 入る in 帯が入る

Tags: words

[From JapanesePod101:](http://blogs.japanesepod101.com/blog/2014/08/08/)

> 十四番のボールは、緑の帯が入っている。
>   The fourteen ball has a green stripe.

I'm not sure how and why 入る is being used here. There doesn't seem to be any clear fit amongst the dictionary meanings of [入る](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/174460/m0u/%E5%85%A5%E3%82%8B/). I usually understand 入る as `to enter/to be inside (intransitive)`, so the stripe instead of the ball being the subject of 入る seems a bit weird - shouldn't the ball be "inside" the stripe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to a [大辞林](http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%AF%E3%81%84%E3%82%8B), “入る (はいる)” also means that something exists on something else.
Thus, your example means that a green stripe is on the ball.

The dictionary provides another example: “ネームの入った便箋” (a letter with your name on it).
In my experience, this meaning of “入る” is used only when something is written or drawn.

A related example is “ひびが入る”, which is listed as another meaning in the dictionary.

Comment: Perhaps (?) that meaning could be explained by framing it as: plain/normal state --> some detail/feature is added (put in). In this case, to a feature-less, monochrome ball you add ("put in") a stripe. This is similar to how 大辞林 puts it: `ある物が他の物の内部・内側に移り` and `入れられたり，付けられたりして，そこにある。`